# C++ Primer 5ed, 7_43

Tags: c++

Hi I have a question when doing the exercise 7.43. The question goes:
"Assume we have a class named NoDefault that has a constructor that takes an int, but has no default constructor. Define a class C that has a member of type NoDefault. Define the default constructor for C."

```
class NoDefault{
  public:
    NoDefault(int i){}
};

class C{

  private:
    NoDefault temp;
  public:
    C(int i):temp(i){}
};

int main(){
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

Why `C(int i):temp(i){}` is not correct?

The error shows:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -o ex7_43 ex7_43.cpp
ex7_43.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ex7_43.cpp:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘C::C()’
ex7_43.cpp:12: note: candidates are: C::C(int)
ex7_43.cpp:7: note:                 C::C(const C&)
```

I know that `C():temp(0){}` compiles find.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `C(int i): temp(i){ }`? Obviously `C(int i);temp(i){}` won't compile.

Comment: When posting question about errors, always include the actual errors, verbatim, complete and unedited, in your question.

Comment: You significantly changed the question after posting.

Comment: corrected a typo, and include the error message in the question

Answer (score 4):

This constructor

```
C(int i):temp(i){}
```

is not the default constructor of the class. However inside main this declaration

```
C c;
```

requires existence of the default constructor of the class. So the compiler issues an error because there is no default constructor.

On the other hand this declaration

```
C():temp(0){}
```

declares the default constructor that can be used in declaration

```
C c;
```

According to the C++ Standard (12.1 Constructors)

> 4 A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument.

You could define the default constructor with parameters but the parameters in this case shall have default arguments. For example

```
C(int i = 0):temp(i){}
```

The above constructor is the default constructor because it can be called without arguments.

And in the exersice there is written:

> Define the default constructor for C

So you could define it either like

```
C():temp(0){}
```

or like

```
C(int i = 0):temp(i){}
```

or even the following way

```
class C{

  private:
    NoDefault temp;
  public:
    C(int i);
};

C::C( int i = 0 ) :temp( i ) {}
```

That is to use the default argument in the definition of the contructor outside the class but before main.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!
And also this could work in main: int i=0; C c(i);

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, but you did not define "the default constructor for C". You defined some other constructor. So, then, much like in `NoDefault`, `C` had no implicit default constructor and could not be instantiated in `main` through the declaration `C c`.

```
C() : temp(1337) {}
```

There you go.